# How to set an XUL key dynamically and securely?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-restartless

I am trying to create a key element dynamically for my bootstrapped add-on. Currently, I create a `keyset` element and append it to `document.getElementById('mainKeyset').parentNode` with `appendChild()` and then create the `key` element (`myKey`) and append it to the `keyset`. I set the `key`'s `id`, `modifiers`, and `key` attributes and then do `myKey.addEventListener('command', function() {myFunction()});` to add a function to the `key`. After this, I can successfully call `myFunction()` by doing `myKey.doCommand()`.  However, when I press the modifiers and key that I assigned in the `key`'s attributes, nothing happens.

I am trying to avoid setting the `command` and `oncommand` attributes because I know there is a security issue with setting `oncommand` dynamically, but maybe I do need to use them somehow?  I have [seen it stated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/key) that a key can not work without command or oncommand set, so perhaps it is not possible to create a key dynamically without setting one of them. My event listener works if I set oncommand to "void(0);" (following the example given [here](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2011/02/firefox-4-restartless-add-ons.html)). However, I don't know if something like that could get pass Mozilla's extension approval process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement about `<key>` elements requiring either a `command` or an `oncommand` attribute is correct. Looking at the [code triggering key handlers](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/c190422547ed/content/xbl/src/nsXBLWindowKeyHandler.cpp#l498), it has an optimization that will ignore any `<key>` element that is either disabled or has neither a  `command` nor an `oncommand` attribute - so the `command` event won't even fire for these elements. I solve this by adding a dummy `oncommand` attribute containing a JavaScript comment:

```js
key.setAttribute("oncommand", "//");
```

But `void(0);` is fine as attribute value as well of course.

There won't be any issues getting this reviewed. The potential security issue you heard about is generating `oncommand` value dynamically, e.g.:

```js
key.setAttribute("oncommand", "foo('" + bar + "')");
```

Depending on the value of `bar` (and particularly when `bar` comes from a website) this can be very dangerous. However, you don't generate the attribute value dynamically, it's always `void(0);` in your case - so no issue there.