# firefox add-on shortcut does not work anymore

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, shortcut

I have used following commands in my browser.xul to set a shortcut for my addon.

```
<keyset id="mainKeyset">
  <key id="key_convert"
       modifiers="accel"
       keycode="VK_F12"
       oncommand="myfunction()" />"
</keyset>
```

It used to work for previous versions of Firefox, but not anymore for newer versions.
has anything changed in the syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That code example looks correct, I suspect that there is some code within `myfunction()` that is failing, so we need more information probably.  Try to replace `myfunction()` with `alert("test")`, that should work.

Answer (score -1):

Some notes:

- You must add it to a keyset, as the key listeners are attached when keyset is added

  - source: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2711165&p=12885299&hilit=mainKeyset#p12885299
- You must set an `oncommand` attribute

  - source: [How to set an XUL key dynamically and securely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779316/how-to-set-an-xul-key-dynamically-and-securely)

Can copy paste this to scratchpad:

```
var keyset = document.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'keyset'); //http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2711165&p=12885299&hilit=mainKeyset#p12885299
//cant use mainKeyset see topic above
var key = document.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'key');
var props = {
  id: 'key_convert',
  modifiers: 'accel',
  keycode: 'VK_F12',
  oncommand: 'alert("tirggered")'
};
for (var p in props) {
  key.setAttribute(p, props[p]);
}
keyset.appendChild(key);
Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').document.documentElement.appendChild(keyset);
```